# Testing React Native app with Espresso. Step by step instructions

Tags: android, react-native, android-espresso

I'm trying to configure e2e testing of my React Native app. The RN version I'm using is 0.56. Unfortunately Detox doesn't support this version on Android and I decided to implement temporarily Espresso tests directly while waiting for Detox official support.

I followed [instructions](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/setup) on setting up Espresso for Android app. Luckily most of that has been already added by Detox. I also created a test file in android/app/src/androidTest/java/[com/package/name/]MainActivityTest.java. Here is its context:

```
package com.package.name;

import android.support.test.espresso.ViewAssertion;
import android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction;
import android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions;
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.LargeTest;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isDisplayed;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withContentDescription;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.allOf;

@LargeTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MainActivityTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void mainActivityTest() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ViewInteraction view = onView(allOf(withContentDescription("onboardingScreen"), isDisplayed()));

        ViewInteraction button = onView(allOf(withContentDescription("login"), isDisplayed()));

        button.perform(click());

        onView(allOf(withContentDescription("currentMealPlanTab"), isDisplayed()));

}
```

...and added { accessible: true, accessibilityLabel: id } to the views I'm testing.

When I run the test either from Android Studio or by issuing "./gradlew connectedAndroidTest" I get java.lang.RuntimeException: No activities found. Did you forget to launch the activity by calling getActivity().

I was unable to find a step by step guide on how to setup Espresso for React Native. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong and how to set it up.

Answer (score 1):

Just started working with Espresso in React Native myself but you may need another annotation here:

```
    @Rule
    @JvmField
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);
```